# View is not updated after call the myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an app that downloads files from another device.

These files are displayed in a `Listview` and I use a custom adapter to display `CheckBox` and a `TextView` for each item of the list.

When my `DownloadActivity` starts, I check the storage directory and display all files that are currently there in the `Listview`. This is working fine.

I can delete files and they disappear.

However, when I download a new file, I try to update the `ArrayList` and the Adapter as well. However, this is not working.

I'm invoking `notifyDataSetChenged()` but no luck.

I believe that should refresh the view and add files as they come over. I got no errors. Just the file that is not displayed on the list.

If I shut the app down and restart, the files will appear when `DownloadActivity` is started.

This is my code so far:

```
public void saveFile(String curSurvey, String curFilename) {
    if (externalDir == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Failed to save survey. No Directories", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else if (curSurvey.length() > 0 && curFilename.length() > 0) {
        FileReadWriteWrapper frww = new FileReadWriteWrapper();
        frww.openOutputWriter(curFilename, externalDir, "/surveys");
        frww.writeToFile(curSurvey);
        frww.closeIOStream();

        if (arrayList == null) {
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        arrayList.add(new FileListItem(false,curFilename + " " + curSurvey.length() + " Bytes" ));                                                                                                                                                                            ;

        if (surveyFileListAdapter == null) {
            surveyFileListAdapter = new SurveyFileListAdapter(arrayList,this);
            surveyListview.setAdapter(surveyFileListAdapter);

        }
        surveyFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this line surveyFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  within the null check?

Comment: No. It's only null the first time it saveFile() executes. But I will try that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem I see is that you aren't updating the list inside the Adapter. This way, your adapter always have the same set of data to be displayed...

```
// Here is your problem.. You are updating the List in the Activity/Fragment
// However, you must update the list inside the adapter.
// Otherwise, the adapter will always display the same items.
arrayList.add(new FileListItem(false,curFilename + " " + curSurvey.length() + " Bytes" ));                                                                                                                                                                            ;

if (surveyFileListAdapter == null) {
    surveyFileListAdapter = new SurveyFileListAdapter(arrayList,this);
    surveyListview.setAdapter(surveyFileListAdapter);
} else {
    // Add this else statement..
    // This way, if the adapter was already created, you just update its list
    // and call notifyDataSetChanged to refresh the screen
    surveyFileListAdapter.updateList(arrayList);
    surveyFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then, your adapter:

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<FileListItem> arrayList) {
    mArrayList = arrayList;
}
```

Note: Instead of updating whole list in the adapter, you can create a method and just add the new item (instead of replacing whole list). For any case, I just tried to point the problematic point to you!

Hope I could help